# Fetch facebook user friends about data(work,education etc...)

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is it Possible to fetch facebook user friends about data like his work details and education details etc currently i am able to get his basic details like id,firstname,lastname,location, name,email by posting this link........

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/10203915299618405?   fields=work&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Anyone out there knows how to do it...please i need some help on this.....I have read somewhere that to fetch above details i must submit my application for review....then only i will be able to fetch the above details..is it correct or is there any other method to fetch the above details without submitting my application for review to  facebook....any sort of guidance will be greatly appreciated...thank you

Answer (score 0):

Friend permissions are deprecated, you can only request data from the user who authorized your App. Check out the changelog for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

You can get data about the authorized user with the `/me` endpoint, for some data you have to add the scope in the authorization process (email, for example).

Comment: that's fine but i am not able to fetch about data(i.e., work and education) of authorised app user's using the above mentioned link...

Comment: k..i will try adding some scope's then